# Is this word 加速度 used ungrammatically?

Tags: word-choice

临汾市乡宁县发展特色产业 跑出乡村振兴加速度 is the title of a news item of Xinhua News Agency on Aug 16, 2023.

As we know, 加速度 is acceleration or accelerated velocity.

Definition of acceleration found online:

A physical quantity whose speed varies in a certain direction.

Force is a condition that changes the motion state of an object, while acceleration is a physical quantity that describes the motion state of an object. Acceleration is not necessarily related to velocity. When the acceleration is high, the velocity can be very small, and when the velocity is high, the acceleration can also be very small.

The report tries to impress the audience that the development in that region is in the fast lane, which is closely related to the image of a car speeding up, hence the phrase 加速度.

Unfortunately, 加速度 does not necessarily mean 高速度, because sometimes it could also mean a retarded speed.

Am I right?

Comment: The same as in the US, the news title often does not follow grammar rules, and can't be fully explained/understood until reading the article. Here, I think it will make better sense if "跑出" is replaced with "為".

Comment: You are 100% correct as a physics scientist, but not as an artist. Just as they say, 正能量. In physics, energy is always positive.

Comment: As I know(I as Chinese), "加速度" in "跑出乡村振兴加速度" is doesn't matter to "A physical quantity whose speed varies in a certain direction.", especially it doesn't matter to physical. **It's just a political slogan (with little practical significance).**

Answer (score 2):

As a Chinese native speaker, I may tell you the 加速度 here is used as a noun and means faster speed.The title of some agencies' article such like XinHua or others always use grammar in a peculiar way, but we don't use this kind of grammar in common writings or speakings. In addition, we call the use of this kind of grammar “官腔”, which means the tone of administrator.

Comment: I believe "As a Chinese native speaker" is irrelevant info when it comes to strengthening your argument. I just wish people stop saying that when they post an answer

Comment: I am agree with "we call the use of this kind of grammar “官腔”, which means the tone of administrator.". It's just a political slogan (with little practical significance).

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't related to Grammar. The simple answer is that media people don't know much about physics. Whoever wrote this title must have had in mind 加速乡村振兴 (accelerate the pace of rural revitalization). And then some day they learned about the word 加速度 (acceleration) somewhere and thought: "That's a nice word so I will use it instead", without realizing it is a very specific concept in physics.

Anyway, even though it looks incorrect in terms of physics, most people can still understand its meaning, and only a few may be provoked. So it is possible that 跑出...加速度 will become a valid expression in contexts not related to physics.

Answer (score 0):

加速度 here shouldn't be confused with the compound word "加速" (accelerate/ acceleration)

加 = add

速度 = speed

加速度 = add speed.

The difference between "acceleration" and "adding speed" is clear,  acceleration means "speeding up", which means things have to be in motion already

"Add speed" means " move things along at a higher speed" It could mean things have not been moving along or moving at a languid pace since the beginning

Answer (score 0):

In typical Chinese fashion you have a phrase, 乡村振兴, wrapped at both ends by

跑出 。。。加速度

跑出乡村振兴 加速度
running rural revival at good speed

临汾市乡宁县发展特色产业 跑出乡村振兴加速度。
The revival and development of characteristic village industries in the rural areas of Lin Fen City in Xiangning County is running at good speed.

Whatever those industries may be!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the word "加速度" in two aspects. As a whole word, it is the translation of the English word "acceleration" in Newton's law of classical physics theory. As a compound word, it is the adjective (or a verb) "加" and the noun "速度". "加" is used in many compound words to indicate that the thing becomes greater. For example,

(1) 加油 - Come on. Make progress. (in sports)

(2) 加强合作 - Strengthening our cooperation.

(3) 加速完成 - Speedy up in the progress.

(4) 加固防线 - Fortify the defense line.

I personally do not like the sentences such as "跑出什么什么加速度". It does not like written by an objective reporter but by a propaganda boaster.

Answer (score 0):

"Grammatically" might be a wrong attempt of interpretation to Chinese language at all.

As I've mentioned in another answer: Chinese become a stream of consciousness or even subconsciousness, but not a communication tool with accuracy anymore (or, maybe never was?).

So, it is more about words, vocabulary and context. Actually, this is not my invention, but what I've learned from a Belgium kid who is very talent on languages and speak fluently Chinese with me, that he said he only learned for less than a year. And he told me that Chinese is actually easy to learn, if only for oral communication. That is because the words are simple and there's no strict gramma but only context matters.

And I agree.

Therefore, for "加速度", in Chinese, it literally means the acceleration of speed. And speed could be any value with function of time. Hope this answer satisfies you.